# CSS/Chrome: YouTube video embed causing unwanted 1px vertical space

Tags: css, google-chrome, youtube

## The problem:

When I embed a Youtube video in my page Chrome displays a vertical 1px white space on the left side of my page.

The problem is limited to **Chrome** and pages with **YouTube embeds**.

## Live example:

- A page **with** the problem (YouTube embed): http://tinyurl.com/978349d
- A page **without** the problem (No YouTube embed):
  http://tinyurl.com/95qq379

## What I've tried:

1. I've tried resizing the video embed to a smaller width but to no
   avail.
2. I've tried dissecting the CSS via Chrome's element inspector but to
   no avail.

## My question:

Can anyone suggest why Chrome is adding this unwanted space whenever a page contains a YouTube embed?

Comment: I see an image but no video on the "page with the problem" example.

Comment: @j08691 he had the links mixed up, the one that said *no YouTube embed* actually had the video. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only fix I could find is to set the `#main` container to width 959px instead of 960px. May not be the right solution but it works

Comment: In lieu of understanding the cause, a solution is the best I can hope and for and yes, I can confirm your solution works.  Thanks for the fix.